# Function to make single hhid dummy vars from duplicated hhid list (with example data code)

Tags: r, matrix

I have data that looks like this in R:

```
df.original <-data.frame(hhid = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1004), item = c("candybar","toycar","chair","candybar", "chair", "candybar", "sled"))
```

I want the data to look like this (column for unique hhid, with expanded dummy variable columns for the items):

```
df.desired  <- data.frame(hhid = c(1001,1002,1003,1004), candybar=c(1,1,1,0), toycar=c(1,0,0,0), chair=c(1,0,0,0), sled=c(0,0,0,1))
```

I'm pretty sure this is a function possible with model.matrix() but for whatever reason I couldn't get it to work and am unfamiliar with matrix manipulation in R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df.desired <- df.original %>%
  mutate(item = as.character(item)) %>%
  mutate(Value = 1) %>%
  spread(item, Value, fill = 0) %>%
  select(hhid, candybar, toycar, chair, sled)
```

#### Update

If you want to use functions only from base R.

```
dat <- table(df.original)
dat2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(dat) 
dat2$hhid <- row.names(dat2)
df.desired <- dat2[, c("hhid", "candybar", "toycar", "chair", "sled")]
row.names(df.desired) <- 1:4
```

Comment: Nice ycw. Works perfectly.