# Tabulate amounts of a variable as individual columns from duplicated ID/number of each category

Tags: r, matrix

I have data in the following format:

```
df.original <-data.frame(hhid = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1004), item = c("candybar","toycar","chair","candybar", "chair", "candybar", "sled"), number= c(2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2))
```

I'd like to have a list of the amounts of each item by hhid in the following way:

```
df.desired  <- data.frame(hhid = c(1001,1002,1003,1004), candybar=c(2,3,3,0), toycar=c(1,0,0,0), chair=c(4,1,0,0), sled=c(0,0,0,2))
```

I can get dummy variables (based on a previous question I had here that was similar but without the amounts) but the table function used in that method just calculates repeats by two columns. For reference the question I am talking about (and used on a different set) is here: [Function to make single hhid dummy vars from duplicated hhid list (with example data code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621773/function-to-make-single-hhid-dummy-vars-from-duplicated-hhid-list-with-example)

I'd prefer to avoid tidyverse if possible and use base functions. I'll have to run this on an offsite linux server that makes it difficult due to firewalls to install packages that the admin haven't already installed (it's possible if it's the only way, just a bit of trouble).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is to convert the `df` from **long** format to **wide** format. R base has `reshape`. This will however not give you a `0` for instances where the value does not exist. It should be and will be `NA`. You can easily replace `NA` with an additional line of code.

```
df.desired  <- reshape(df.original, idvar = "hhid", timevar = "item", direction = "wide")
df.desired[is.na(df.desired)] <- 0
```

Comment: Indeed. That is exactly what I am looking for Drj. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table` function.

```
x = table(df.original)

x1 = (x[,,number=1])

x2 = (x[,,number=2])
x2[(x2 == 1)] = 2

x3 = (x[,,number=3])
x3[(x3 == 1)] = 3

x4 = (x[,,number=4])
x4[(x4 == 1)] = 4

x1+x2+x3+x4
```

not the best answer but hope it helps you!

Best,